# How do I access Secret Environment Variables in my c# code

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm running tests (Selenium) in an Azure Pipeline in Azure Devops I have secret environment variables setup for user id & password (For the selenium robot to log in with) how do I access these in my c# unit test?  Or is there a way to pass these as command line arguments to the test even so how do I access them?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable` ?

Comment: @MarcGravell Tried that the encrypted Environment variables just comes up blank :|

Answer (score 1):

Ok I figured it out

The correct process is to set an Environment variable in Powershell or Bash to your secret Environment variable.  use the ##vso method to set the variable.  Here's my pipeline task if anybody wants to suggest a better way please go ahead

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=TestPassword]$(TPassword)"
```